# What happens with Dovecot dsync replication if the other server is unavailable?

Tags: email, dovecot

I'm looking at setting up another mailserver at one of our other offices using Postfix and Dovecot. We have a third party spam filter that can relay incoming mail to two servers using SMTP, and if one of the servers is unavailable it will queue the mail until it's back online.

I was wondering if something similar happens when using dsync to synchronise two Dovecot instances. I've not been able to find a definitive answer online.

If I set up master/master relication with dsync I understand that changes a user makes with their IMAP client on one server (A) will then be replicated over to the other server (B). But if B goes offline and the user carries on making changes on A, will those changes automatically be replicated to B when it come back online? Or will A and B then be out of sync and require some sort of manual intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dsync is 'idempotent' and will synchronise from whatever state you are currently in; there is no queue of pending changes as there is with something like MySQL replication.

This means that, when server B comes back up, the next time a dsync is triggered, you will end up with both servers back in sync.  No manual intervention is required, and they will get back into sync even if all the mails filesystem on B was wiped (though it might take a bit of time to achieve this).

You would probably want to have users normally access only via server A, and in the event of A failing and your proxy redirecting them to B, remove A from the proxy pool until your dsync has completed and A is once again in sync.